# How to get all columns' names for all the tables in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-schema

would like to know how to get all column names , data type and from which tables in one Oracle database

Below is for MySQL database and i am looking the samething for Oracle database.

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'your_db'
order by table_name,ordinal_position
```

Comment: Doesn't Oracle have information_schema too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_tab_cols
 ORDER BY table_name, column_name, column_id
```

after connecting to the schema from which you want to get the related information.

Comment: thank Barbaros, i run the above script  but returns empty tables

Comment: you're welcome @foy , are you sure there are tables created within the current schema ? Try to create a table first, and then run the query.

Comment: update you later on once i confirm if i have the right to do so thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get column names and info of all tables **owned by the current user**

```
SELECT *
FROM USER_TAB_COLS
```

Get column names and info of all tables **accessible to the current user**

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
```

Get column names and info of all tables in the **entire database**

```
SELECT *
FROM DBA_TAB_COLS
```

More information can be found in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/ALL_TAB_COLS.html#GUID-85036F42-140A-406B-BE11-0AC49A00DBA3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query,

***Following Query will give you the tables of a specific schema:***

```
select ut.*,uc.*
  from user_tables ut
  join user_tab_cols uc
    on ut.table_name = uc.table_name
 where lower(ut.table_name) = 'table_name'
 order by ut.table_name,uc.internal_column_id;
```

***Following Query will give you the list of all tables from your current scheam and the tables you are having access to from other schema as well* :**

```
select *
  from all_tables ut
  join all_tab_cols uc
    on ut.table_name = uc.table_name
 where ut.owner = '<schema_name_in_upper>'
 order by ut.table_name,uc.internal_column_id;
```

Comment: thank sujit, i will try your script and let you know the result